# How to set xAxis display certain value independent from entry using mpchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

For example, I have a data set like following:

```
val dataSetX = {101, 205, 210, 445, 505}
val dataSetY = {50, 100, 150, 200, 250}
```

The labels on the xAxis of the chart will be 101, 205, 295, 445, 505.

But I want them to be 100,200,300,400,500, without changing the data.

What do I do?

Comment: Hi! You can customise your x axis. For that, you need to create a new class ``` class XAxisValueFormatter: ValueFormatter()``` and round your values in a function ```override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {}```. Don't forget to assign ```xAxis.valueFormatter = XAxisValueFormatter()```

Comment: With this approach, the highlight line point on the xAxis will be the wrong number.
I want them to point to a blank section, take Entry(101,50) for example, point to the blank just near the 100 label on xAxis.

Comment: Hmmm. Have no idea, unfortunately. Perhaps you can check this solution but with integer: https://medium.com/@spmandrus/ios-charts-custom-y-axis-values-e03cac8850c
It's for iOS-Charts, but they're very alike to MPAndroidChart library. Perhaps it's the same as you explained in your previous comment. But let's hope it will give you an insight at least :)

Comment: @Lilya it's kinda solution im using right now. But im still having some issue like even if i force it to show all the xaxis label, it won't until I scale up the chart in X direction.
It's really bothering me.

Comment: please, provide the other stackoverflowers with the code you're using to achieve the desired result. This would be helpful

Comment: @Lilya Do you have any idea how the xAxis decide which value to show as label based on different scale level?

Comment: Hi. As far as I know from the docs, it's calculated automatically unless setLabelCount is set by force. Also, you can set a custom min and max value for the axis:```/**
     * Set a custom minimum value for this axis. If set, this value will not be calculated
     * automatically depending on
     * the provided data. Use resetAxisMinValue() to undo this. Do not forget to call
     * setStartAtZero(false) if you use
     * this method. Otherwise, the axis-minimum value will still be forced to 0.
     */
    public void setAxisMinimum(float min) {}```

Comment: Anyone found a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to render custom labels independent from the Data Entry List you need to implement a custom `XAxisRenderer` and override the function `fun drawLabels(c: Canvas?, pos: Float, anchor: MPPointF?)` which is called when the labels are ready to be drawn on the `Canvas`. The default implementation uses the `mXAxis.mEntryCount` and `mXAxis.mEntries` to render the labels in the xAxis which are calculated internally by the library. What you can do is to modify the superclass implementation by overriding it without calling the `super.drawLabels(c, pos, anchor)` method and make the adjustments needed to handle your custom labels. Below i will describe how you can achieve this.

1.) First declare your `CustomXAxisRenderer` which extends from `XAxisRenderer` like the below example:

```
class CustomXAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?, xAxis: XAxis?, trans: Transformer?, renderXArray : Array<Float>, formatter: ValueFormatter)
    : XAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans) {

    private val xArray : Array<Float>
    private val xValueFormatter: ValueFormatter

    init {
        xArray = renderXArray
        xValueFormatter = formatter
    }

    override fun drawLabels(c: Canvas?, pos: Float, anchor: MPPointF?) {
        //don't call the super class to draw the default x points
        //super.drawLabels(c, pos, anchor)

        val labelRotationAngleDegrees = mXAxis.labelRotationAngle
        val centeringEnabled = false//mXAxis.isCenterAxisLabelsEnabled

        val positions = FloatArray(xArray.size * 2)

        for(i in positions.indices step 2){

            // only fill x values
            if (centeringEnabled) {
                positions[i.toInt()] = mXAxis.mCenteredEntries[(i / 2).toInt()]
            } else {
                positions[i.toInt()] = xArray[(i / 2).toInt()]
            }
        }

        mTrans.pointValuesToPixel(positions)

        for(i in positions.indices step 2){

            var x = positions[i]

            if (mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsX(x)) {
                val label = xValueFormatter.getAxisLabel(xArray[i / 2], mXAxis)
                if (mXAxis.isAvoidFirstLastClippingEnabled) {

                    // avoid clipping of the last
                    if (i / 2 == xArray.size - 1 && xArray.size > 1) {
                        val width = Utils.calcTextWidth(mAxisLabelPaint, label).toFloat()
                        if (width > mViewPortHandler.offsetRight() * 2 && x + width > mViewPortHandler.chartWidth)
                            x -= width / 2

                        // avoid clipping of the first
                    } else if (i == 0) {
                        val width = Utils.calcTextWidth(mAxisLabelPaint, label).toFloat()
                        x += width / 2
                    }
                }
                drawLabel(c, label, x, pos, anchor, labelRotationAngleDegrees)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2.)Then you can use it like the below:

```
//prepare an Array of the x points to render independent of the x points in the Data Entry List
//below values must be between AxisMinimum and AxisMaximum
val renderXArray = arrayOf<Float>(0f, 150f, 250f, 350f, 400f, 433f, 505f)
//and set a custom XAxisRenderer
chart.setXAxisRenderer(CustomXAxisRenderer(chart.getViewPortHandler(), chart.getXAxis(), chart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT), renderXArray, object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        return value.toInt().toString()
    }
}))
```

In case you need to return a specific Label-String based on the value you can use the `ValueFormatter` like the below:

```
chart.setXAxisRenderer(CustomXAxisRenderer(chart.getViewPortHandler(), chart.getXAxis(), chart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT), renderXArray, object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        return when (value) {
            0f -> "A"
            150f -> "B"
            250f -> "C"
            350f -> "D"
            400f -> "E"
            433f -> "F"
            505f -> "G"
            else -> ""
        }
    }
}))
```

**Full Example:**

```
chart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.chart)

//set xAxis properties
val xAxis = chart.xAxis
xAxis.setDrawLabels(true)
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true)
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true)
xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
xAxis.axisLineWidth = 1.5f

//set xAxis Min/Max and Granularity
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f)
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(505f)
xAxis.setGranularity(1f)
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true)

//set axisLeft properties
val axisLeft = chart.axisLeft
axisLeft.setDrawLabels(true)
axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(true)
axisLeft.setDrawZeroLine(true)
axisLeft.axisLineWidth = 1.5f
axisLeft.setDrawTopYLabelEntry(true)

//set axisRight properties
val axisRight = chart.axisRight
axisRight.setDrawLabels(false)
axisRight.setDrawGridLines(false)
axisRight.setDrawZeroLine(false)
axisRight.setDrawAxisLine(false)

//prepare the Entry points
val values: ArrayList<Entry> = ArrayList()
values.add(Entry(101f, 50f))
values.add(Entry(205f, 100f))
values.add(Entry(210f, 150f))
values.add(Entry(445f, 200f))
values.add(Entry(505f, 250f))

//set the LineDataSet
val set1 = LineDataSet(values, "")
set1.setDrawCircles(true);
set1.setDrawValues(true);

//prepare LineData and set them to LineChart
val dataSets: ArrayList<ILineDataSet> = ArrayList()
dataSets.add(set1)
val data = LineData(dataSets)
chart.setData(data)
chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
chart.legend.isEnabled = false

//prepare an Array of the x points to render independent of the x points in the Data Entry List
//below values must be between AxisMinimum and AxisMaximum
val renderXArray = arrayOf<Float>(0f, 150f, 250f, 350f, 400f, 433f, 505f)
//and set a custom XAxisRenderer
chart.setXAxisRenderer(CustomXAxisRenderer(chart.getViewPortHandler(), chart.getXAxis(), chart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT), renderXArray, object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        return value.toInt().toString()
    }
}))
```

**Value Result:**

[image: value_result]

**Label Result:**

[image: label_result]

**Note:** This was tested with version `'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'`

Comment: Your answer is good but you need to add :
`init { xAxis.valueFormatter = xValueFormatter }` at the beggining of CustomXAxisRenderer